# Redirect to a specific page using session variable

Tags: asp.net, session, redirect, webforms

We are working a big project here in ASP.NET\VB.NET
The web site is a tool to manage projects. 
We use session variables to naviguate between ProjectID selected by the user in some search page. So say the user selects "Project X" in the result page of whatever search on the website. We get the ProjectID from the database and pass it to a session variable to load up the Project Info page.

Now the good stuff, we produce multiple reports in Excel linked with the webpage. We'd like to add a link in the Excel page to redirect the user into the selected project info page. Since we're using session variable and it's server side, we have a hard time figuring out how to do this. Is there anyway to pass the info in the URL to affect the session variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offhand, when you generate the page your on the server, generate the url and put the parameter into the querystring.  Then when you load the linked page, you check the query string first, if a value exists use it over the session...

Comment: Thank you sir, any more infos on that query string... say I want to load up projectID 4524, how do I build this query string ?

Comment: Take a look at the following.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/QueryString.aspx  If you have any other questions, let me know.

Comment: The link is clicked from an outside program (i.e. Excel). How could I make it work ?

Comment: How does the link get generated in excel?  Does your asp.net site create the file (I'm assuming xls) that's loaded in excel or is it created by hand?